# XYLineChart rendering the data as discrete lines instead of one shape

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am exporting a `XYLineChart` to PDF using iTextPDF. The plot renderer however produces some ugly glitches which seem to come from it drawing each line separately, instead of producing a connected polyline / contiguous shape...

The following is a zoom in when using `setBaseShapesFilled(false)` and `setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(2f))`:

[image]

Are there any ways to work around this problem and have the polyline rendered as one shape, so that the segments are properly connected?

Answer (score 2):

There is an explicit switch `drawSeriesLineAsPath` with is *false* by default. Enabling it:

```
val r = plot.getRenderer.asInstanceOf[XYLineAndShapeRenderer]
r.setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true)
```

Produces the correct result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, it *does* use a `GeneralPath` with `lineTo` statements (unless there is a point for which `!p.isLastPointGood()`—which shouldn't be the case (I think it only is bad if it's null)...

So I don't know why this is happening. A workaround is to use the spline renderer

```
val r = new XYSplineRenderer
r.setBaseShapesVisible(false)
plot.setRenderer(r)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also consider altering the stroke's rendering attributes:

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
XYItemRenderer r = plot.getRenderer();
r.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(
    16f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I did try that. But with width = 2, the rounding caps etc. didn't work out, I have either gaps or overshoot.

Comment: Sorry this answer wasn't useful to you. Are you using Windows? It works for me on Aqua and GTK even at low point sizes.

Comment: I am using OS X, Java 6 with Java renderer. The gaps appear at least with the stroke width I'm using (2), no matter if `CAP_BUTT`, `CAP_ROUND`, ... Perhaps it works in your example, because the thickness is large enough. As I said, the crucial bit is `r.setDrawSeriesLineAsPath(true)` as far as I can see.

Comment: You might experiment with `System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz", "true")`.